# How to set environment variable with dot in name using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to set environment variable in powershell that has dot in name.
This line throws an error:

`$env:Test.Env.Var1 = "test111"`

```
The property 'Var1' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1
+ $env:Test.Env.Var1 = "test111"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Is it possible to set "Test.Env.Var1" variable without using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` method?

Comment: `${env.test.value} = 'value'`

Comment: By "Comma" you mean a dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by

`${env:Test.Env.Var1} = 'value'`

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6#variable-names-that-include-special-characters)

Thanks to @4c74356b41 who provided answer in comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

```
${env:test.value} = 'value'
```

Note the colon after `env`. This works in both `powershell` and `pwsh`

Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#variable-names-that-include-special-characters